# Set root view width equal to dynamic label's width

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using XIB to populate tableview of a chat app (messages). It contains a view and a label on it. The label's text continuously changes. How can I find the width of label and then set width of parent view equal to that?

I'm a newbie to swift. So, in this way, is it possible to set height also?

I have set the number of lines to '0' of the uilabel
[image]

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/27056980/3150830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the "Message Text" label is the only subview within the parent view, you could set the parent view's height and width like so:

```
if let subview = view.subviews.first {
    // where `view` is your parent view and `subview` is your text label
    view.frame.size.width = subview.frame.width
    view.frame.size.height = subview.frame.height  
}
```

Comment: But how can I find width and height of uilabel?

Comment: That's what the `subview` is in my example. `subview.frame.width` and `subview.frame.height`